# How to ng-checked checkbox in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some list to display for user reputation census.
With sigle option radio button I use this code and work great when user answer and then when he return on the same question to check his previous answer.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input name="myName" value="{{item.id}}" type="radio" 
     ng-selected="myModel==item.id" ng-model="myModel"/>{{item.text}}
</li>
```

But with multiple option I've to use check box and I don't know how write code to mantain checked previous answer. Now I use this code but it doesn't work:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input name="myName" checklist-value="{{item.id}}" type="checkbox" 
     ng-checked="myModel==item.id" checklist-model="myModel"/>{{item.text}}
 </li>
```

Any help, please?

**UPDATE**

Now i have a model array with multiple value inside (myModel). With following code i'm not able to check correct items.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
<input name="myName" checklist-value="{{item.id}}" type="checkbox" 
 ng-checked="myModel[$index]==item.id" checklist-model="myModel"/>{{item.text}}
</li>
```

Where is my error?
Thanks

Comment: Can you create any fiddle or plunker???

Comment: Sorry, no. Because application is very big...

Comment: you could dynamically add a property to your item object like item.is_checked to determine whether the item is checked or not

Answer (score 0):

Try following snipet

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input name="myName" type="checkbox"  ng-model="ngModel"
     ng-checked="myModel===item.id"  ng-true-value="{{item.id}}"/>{{item.text}}
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <label ng-repeat="language in languages">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-checklist-model="profile.languageId" data-checklist-value="language.languageId">
                    {{language.Language}} &nbsp;
                </label>
```

It is working

Step:

1. you need to download "checklist-model.js" file ([link](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/))
2. you need to inject "checklist-model" module in your app.
3. then your code will work.